# Храм "Всех скорбящих Радост(и/ь)"

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

Как правильно: *«храм "Всех скорбящих Радости"»* или *"Всех скорбящих Радость"?*

Всегда думал, что падеж распространяется на "радость", поэтому правильно *"радости",* но сейчас попались варианты и с Ь. Это неправильно?

Да, забыл пояснить для тех, кто не знает: есть икона Богородицы "Всех скорбящих Радост*" (кстати, тут тоже вопрос, как правильно), в честь неё строят храмы.

Answer (score 2):

Дело-то не в "распространении" падежа.
*Храм (чего?) Радости.

Храм (какой, как называется) "Радость"*

Грамматически и то и другое возможно. В церковной практике основная форма -"Всех скорбящих радость" (по первому стиху стихиры). И если уж вы пишете в кавычках, то нет причин её ставить в косвенный падеж. *Храм "Всех скорбящих Радость".*

Это касается и иконы, причем в первую очередь именно её, поскольку храм (а таких много) в честь иконы и называют. Полное название звучит примерно так. *Храм [в честь] иконы Божией Матери "Всех скорбящих Радость" На Ордынке)*

Без кавычек возможно и в родительном падеже, это касается и иконы и храма, но такие названия неофициальные.

Comment: Спасибо, Ирина! Да, конечно, я понимаю, что название храма подразумевает и полностью звучит как "храм (в честь) иконы...". А вот такая трактовка — храм (который называется / под названием) "Всех скорбящих Радость") — даже в голову не приходила да и не особенно нравится и теперь. То есть "Всех скорбящих Радость" как само название... странно как-то.

Comment: А как вы хотели-то? Только так, это название. И иконы, и - опосредовано - храма. Или тогда уж в дательном падеже, по стиху, на церковнославянском. ***Икона кому?***. «Всех скорбящих Радосте и обидимых Заступнице…» https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85_%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C Но последний вариант ("Икона кому") в современном языке не считается нормативным. Это не памятник.

Comment: Хм... Я могу это воспринять как название, но только как разговорный вариант ***без слова "храм".*** Например, *Пойдём сходим во "Всех скорбящих Радость"* или *Я был во "Всех скорбящих Радости".* То есть падеж по тому, что говоришь, а не родительный от иконы. Хотя с творительным сложно придумать хороший пример и необычно бы звучало. Опять же, повторюсь, я бы склонял так и не говорил "храм" только в разговорной речи.

Comment: Артем, а что вас смущает-то? Почему икона не может называться "Радость"? *Кинотеатр "Родина"* или колхоз *"Красный пролетарий"* вас не удивляет? Даже *колбаса "Собачья радость"* - тот же случай, только название вымышленное. Вы же не назовете её колбасой "Собачьей радости"?

Comment: *Вы же не назовете её колбасой "Собачьей радости"?* Конечно, нет, но потому, что нет причин для этого. А когда что-то относится к чему-то и сам собой возникает падеж, уже не получается такое "название" приравнять к любому из Ваших примеров. Даже не понимаю подробнее почему и как это ещё объяснить...

Comment: Да вы не к примеру приравняйте. Вы к названию иконы. Ну хорошо, пусть не колбаса. *Печенье "Детская радость".* Прична есть. http://www.edimdoma.ru/retsepty/67235-ovsyanoe-pechenie-detskaya-radost Не будете же говорить "печенье детской радости"? Так почему с иконой затруднения-то?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что главное слово в названии "радость"? А "всех скорбящих" - это **чья** радость? и там родительный - притяжательный?

Comment: Всё, я понял. Икона действительно "Всех скорбящих Радость" — назыв**а**ется так, убедили! А храм: строго иконы "Всех скорбящих Радость", но просто (разговорный вариант) — храм "Всех скорбящих Радости", п. ч. подразумевается, что иконы и род. п. это показывает. Но на разговорный вариант нету строгих правил; может, можно говорить и "Радость", а может, даже это признают или признали уже правильным, но мне всё равно в обычной речи хочется склонять. Иногда даже знаешь, что что-то по правилам не склоняется, но хочется в простой речи склонять (на самом деле такое не слишком часто бывает).

Comment: *Вы понимаете, что главное слово в названии "радость"? А "всех скорбящих" - это чья радость? и там родительный - притяжательный?* Понимаю, конечно.

Comment: Тогда я просто не понимаю причину ваших затруднений ... Ладно, замнем.

Comment: Всё, затруднения закончились. Благодаря Вам я вроде разобрался. Спасибо за диалог в комментариях! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Помимо храма на Большой Ордынке, в первопрестольной ныне действуют еще четыре приходских храма во имя иконы **«Всех скорбящих Радость».**

Существует **песнопение в честь этой иконы**: Всех скорбящих **Радосте** и обидимых **Заступнице**, и алчущих **Питательнице,** странных Утешение, обуреваемых Пристанище, больных Посещение, немощных Покров и Заступнице, Жезле старости, Мати Бога Вышнего, **Ты еси Пречистая,** потщися, молимся, спастися рабом Твоим.

О Пресвятая и Преблагословенная **Дево**, **Владычице Богородице!**

Скорее всего, во всех этих формах **звательный падеж, то есть это обращение.**